# Merge 2 rows in Pandas based on a given condition in a column

Tags: pandas, numpy

How to merge 2 cells in the Pandas dataframe when one of the cells of the other column is empty

```py
lst = [['tom', 'reacher', 25], ['krish', 'pete', 30], 
   ['', '', 26], ['juli', 'williams', 22]]
df = pd.DataFrame(lst,columns=['FName','LName','Age'],dtype=float)

In [4]:df
Out[4]: 
   FName     LName   Age
0    tom   reacher  25.0
1  krish      pete  30.0
2                   26.0
3   juli  williams  22.0
```

The ouput which I want is:

```
In [6]:df
Out[6]: 
   FName     LName    Age
0    tom   reacher     25
1  krish      pete  30,26
2   juli  williams     22
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO , [please don't post images of code or data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) as no one can reproduce your data and code , also please check [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and try and post a small sample dataframe and expected output with your non working code

Comment: what columns do  you want to combinate?

Comment: Ok, will check it out and edit the question, thanku!

Comment: How working my solution? In real data are always empty both Names? Or possible empty only one of them?

Answer (score 0):

First find empty cells in a column `col1`, then merge them to other column `col2` and replace.

```
idx = df[df[col1] == ""].index # i guess definition of empty is ""
df.loc[idx,col1]  = df.loc[idx][col2] + df.loc[idx][col1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If always empty strings for both columns only is possible repalce them to missing values `NaN`s and forward filling them, so possible aggregate `join`:

```
df[['FName','LName']] = df[['FName','LName']].replace('', np.nan).ffill()
print (df[['FName','LName']])
   FName     LName
0    tom   reacher
1  krish      pete
2  krish      pete
3   juli  williams

df['Age'] = df['Age'].astype(int).astype(str)
df = df.groupby(['FName','LName'])['Age'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
print (df)
   FName     LName    Age
0   juli  williams     22
1  krish      pete  30,26
2    tom   reacher     25
```

Comment: What if there are more than 3 columns? same as the Age column. How to group by then?

Comment: Then use `df.groupby(['FName','LName', 'another col'])['Age'].apply(','.join).reset_index()`